# Way to influence readers subconscious to memorize technical data?

Tags: memory, consciousness

I'm writing a technical book. Is there any studies/books on how can I influence the readers subconscious to help them memorize the technical data easier? Preferably ways that do not involve images, styles, etc.. as such techniques are not suitable for technical books.

Comment: Why are images, styles, etc. not suitable for technical books? Is that your belief/experience or who told you that? I have read several technical books that use metaphors...

Answer (score 2):

Priming involves the perception of similar elements between information. The similarity between information influences the memory as it has already been primed by previous memory traces.

I do know of a study that suggests that when simple contours of an image are primed before complex versions of those contours, those contours are rated more positively [(Reber *et al*., 2004)](http://bora.uib.no/bitstream/handle/1956/594/BORA_PSPR04.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y).

The study relates to the theory of processing fluency, which proposes that the visual information is more liked because the information is more compatible than it would be otherwise (if the complex contour was shown without the simple one) that's only one part of the theory. The article is called:

The most simple answer is to relate the information with previously memorized information as it may be more likely to be recalled because it is connected to other memories.

**Reference**
[Reber *et al*., Processing fluency and aesthetic pleasure: Is beauty in the perceiver's processing experience? *Personality and Social Psychology Review* ( 2004); **8**(4): 364–382](http://bora.uib.no/bitstream/handle/1956/594/BORA_PSPR04.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Comment: Welcome to CogSci and thank you for your references answer. Great.  Could you edit your post to make it more scientifically appropriate? The first sentence is kind of distracting from the core of your answer. Also, you can add a link to the article which I will try to do now as an example.

Comment: Sorry about that, my edit overrode yours. - I've added your edit, if I am right :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use priming but that assumes that the reader is already familiar with the subject or has read about connected topics. Priming has various aspects but with your requirements you just eliminated the most important ones: images, styles etc. Read more about priming, I am not an expert, there might be more than the above

Comment: Could you explain what priming is and add references?